# Unused argument error in R: swirl functions module

Tags: r

I'm new to R and am working through the Swirl module on functions. It's asking me the following:

**Try using evaluate() along with an anonymous function to return the last element of the vector c(8, 4, 0). Your anonymous function should only take one argument which should be a variable `x`.**

The response I gave is:

```
evaluate(function(x){x[length(x)]}, c(8, 4, 0))
```

Which produced the following error message:

```
Error in evaluate(function(x) { : unused argument (c(8, 4, 0))
```

Can you please explain why it isn't using the c(8,4,0) argument?

Comment: The task you are describing is from the `R Programming - Functions` module, not `vectors`.

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like your environment has a `evaluate()` function, that is not the same as what you are supposed to have. When I execute your code in that Swirl class, I works and is correct.

What does your output look like, when you run `evaluate`, without the parenthesis?

For me it looks like this:

```
evaluate
> function(func, dat){
>   func(dat)
> }
> <bytecode: 0x7fc7512eb348>
```

Comment: It looks like that's the issue. Right now it's showing: `evaluate> function(x) {c(8,4,0)}`. I've tried to change it back to what you've shown using `evaluate<-function(func, dat) {func(dat)}`, but Swirl just keeps telling me `Almost! Try again.` How do I change it without signing in as a different user?

Comment: I don't know exactly how Swirl works under the hood, but I would think when you execute `evaluate<-function(func, dat) {func(dat)}` that should reset it, eventhough you'll get the `Try again!` reaction. After that just provide the correct answer. If that doesn't work I would try starting over the module.